# Best way to set reusable property in Jenkinsfile

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins pipeline shared library can send notification on demand. The user basically has to send the the notifcation channel details like slack channel name or email id for each stage that he wants notifcation.

I do not want user to repeat this property in every stage but rather define it once in Jenkinsfile and I can use that. What would be the best way to set this variable?

Sample:

```
// this properties needs to be accessed by my groovy files
def properties = "channelNm,token"
node('myNode'){

stage('checkout'){
   slackNotify = "yes"
   .....
 }
 stage('compile'){
   slackNotify = "yes"
   .....
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use Jenkins shared library you can create a configuration class and you can expose a DSL script that allows you modifying your configuration object. Take a look at following example. Let's say you have a class called `NotificationConfig` located in `src` folder:

*src/NotificationConfig.groovy*

```
@Singleton
class NotificationConfig {
    String slackChannelName
    String email
    String otherStuff
}
```

This class is a singleton which means that you can get instance (a single one) of this with `NotificationConfig.instance`. Now, let's say you have a DSL script called `notificationConfig.groovy` located in `vars` folder:

*vars/notificationConfig.groovy*

```
#!groovy

def call(Closure body) {
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = NotificationConfig.instance
    body()
}
```

This is a very simple script that delegates closure body to be executed in context of `NotificationConfig` object. Now let's take a look at very simple scripted pipeline that uses `notificationConfig` DSL to set some configuration values:

*Jenkinsfile*

```
notificationConfig {
    email = 'test@test.com'
    slackChannelName = 'test'
}

node {
    stage('Test') {
        echo NotificationConfig.instance.email
    }
}
```

When I run this simple pipeline I see:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] echo
test@test.com
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

As you can see you can expose with such DSL `NotificationConfig` object and let pipeline to define its own values and then access these values in the shared library with `NotificationConfig.instance` object.

> **ATTENTION**: you can always set up some default values in `NotificationConfig` object so library users can override them in their pipelines or rely on defaults if needed.

This is pretty popular pattern in Jenkins Pipeline shared libraries. You can read more about it in this Jenkins blog post - https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/10/02/pipeline-templates-with-shared-libraries/

Comment: But wouldn't this mean I have to pass the "NotificationConfig.instance.email" or any other paramters that i set once, in every stage? The reason being, if I need to call var/notificationConfig.groovy from another var/javaCompile.groovy..I cannot make that call.

Comment: You call `notificationConfig` DSL once (in the beginning of the pipeline) and then you can use `NotificationConfig.instance` object anywhere you need it - you can refer to it from the body of the stage as well as from the body of another DSL script like `var/javaCompile.groovy` and so on.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak can you provide reference version for Jenkins core and Pipeline plugin to work? Trying to use that pattern on my Jenkins instance ends in throwing `NullPointerException` when accessing `instance` / `getInstance()` of the Singleton class. Same problem is described here [jenkins-scripted-pipeline-singleton-null-pointer-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609080/jenkins-scripted-pipeline-singleton-null-pointer-exception)